# how to play sound file which is on my web server and run in background when user click "Home" button...?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I'm new to audio handling in ios.
1.I want to know that if I have web server on which I have some audio files. And through my iOS application user can play that file, allow them to forward or reverse functionality, pause etc.
2.And when user click on "Home" button sound file not pause or stop at that time, file play in background uptill user not close the application properly...

main thing is application play file online and not whole file download on user device

if any of the one answer is possible plz help

Thanks

Comment: Regarding the streaming, search for `implementing RTSP for iOS`. As for your second question, `Playing audio in the background on iOS`. (This site is not for asking people to do your work for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching things here I'm with answer.for run application in background playing songs, step is as below

1. in your application info.plist file add "Application does not run in background" to "YES"
2. in your application info.plist file add "YES"Required background modes" and set "App plays audio"
3. in your .m file

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"select" ofType:@"mp3"]];

       NSError *error;
       audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];

       if (error)
       {
           NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
       } else {
           [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
           [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

           [audioPlayer play];
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Streaming Audio Services is possible. you should using a `AVPlayer`(not `AVAudioPlayer` `AVAuioPlayer` is not available Streaming Services.)

This apple Sample Code [StitchedStreamPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/StitchedStreamPlayer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010092) is good for you.

This code Streaming Movie Play Sample, but also available Audio Service.

Comment: I try this application, when I try to play youtube video with pasting youtube video url, it fire me error, I don't think it will work with video's. For audio file it works good,plz suggest...!?!

Comment: Youtube Video url is not page URL, specified URL export from page URL using javascript. refer a this opensource. [YOUTUBE_VIDEO](https://github.com/comonitos/youtube_video)

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply, yeah I think you're right but may it help me further...!?!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to user this github project https://github.com/jfricker/AudioStreamer
You can control forward and reverse for audio in it. I have used this in one of my project and the performance is really good.